# Avoiding account enumeration when implementing login backoff?

Tags: security, user-experience

I'd like to lock user accounts in my web application for some amount of time that is a function of the number of failed login attempts.

I have two seemingly mutually exclusive goals:

a) prevent an account enumeration vulnerability from occurring: if someone entering an email can lock an account after a certain number of tries and get an error message different from the regular login error, account enumeration is possible.

b) provide a good user experience. if users don't know that a lockout has occurred, they may a) increase the lockout time without knowing it and b) enter the correct password a bunch of times and keep receiving the lockout message, which is the same as the login failure message.

The best idea I've had so far seems to be to email users when a lockout occurs. Many people have their email programs open during work hours, but it's not guaranteed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good question. One way you could go about it is this:

- A *failed* password attempt on an account that has been locked will produce the usual 'Invalid username or password.' message
- A *successful* password attempt on an account that has been locked will produce a 'This email address has been locked for X time.'

If it was the attacker trying to log in, all failed passwords will result in the generic message and they will have no hints to whether the email is valid.

If it was the user trying to log in, all failed passwords will be their fault for forgetting and they can act appropriately (ie. Forgot your password). A successful password attempt will show the locked message and they will understand why they can't log in.

"Doesn't this defeat the purpose of locked accounts since the attacker can continue making attempts until they get the locked message?" Kind of - I think it's a trade off. The above method gives the attacker no hints on valid emails - they have to go all or nothing. If they do manage to guess both email and password, they will be locked out for a significant amount of time for which the real user will have received an email and can change their password accordingly.

If you decide not to show a locked message when a successful password is entered, you run the risk of a frustrated user (but may not be a problem, since they will most likely go to a 'forgot password' form if you provide one). Either way, I would definitely give the user a warning email when there have been too many password attempts.